# How to perform an eigendecomposition of a general complex matrix with arbitrary precision in C/C++

Tags: c++, eigenvalues, precision, eigen

I need to obtain the Eigenvectors of a general complex matrix, but with quadruple precision. Is anyone aware of a means to do this?

I currently use Tux Eigen, and I see that in their unsupported modules, they offer arbitrary precision using MPFR C++, however this appears to be for real numbers only. Perhaps this could be augmented to complex numbers in some way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might try boost.multiprecision with Eigen.

Comment: @user14717 thanks for the suggestion, but boost::multiprecision appears not to play nicely with Eigen, unless there is a way that I am not aware of

Comment: I've never had a problem using boost::multiprecision with Eigen.

Comment: the simple lines; typedef Matrix<boost::multiprecision::complex128, Dynamic, Dynamic> MatrixXcmp;
  MatrixXcmp C = MatrixXcmp::Random(8,8);
  cout<<C<<endl; invoke several errors starting with;
Eigen/src/Core/NumTraits.h:34:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘ceil(boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::complex_adaptor<boost::multiprecision::backends::float128_backend>, (boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option)0>)’
     return int(ceil(-log10(NumTraits<Real>::epsilon())));
                ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: using std::ceil?

Comment: I suppose it must be from std as I haven't told it to get ceil from anywhere else. It is something Eigen is invoking somewhere, as I have made no reference to ceil within my own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It transpires that it is reasonably straightforward to utilise MPFR C++ complex numbers within Tux Eigen;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>
#include <Eigen/LU>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/MPRealSupport>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;
using namespace mpfr;

int main(){
  // set precision to 128 bits (double has only 53 bits)
  mpreal::set_default_prec(128);
  typedef Matrix<complex<mpreal>, Dynamic, Dynamic> MatrixXcmp;
  MatrixXcmp C = MatrixXcmp::Random(8,8);
  ComplexEigenSolver<MatrixXcmp> ces;
  ces.compute(C);
  return 0;
}
```

one first needs to obtain MPFR C++, available at http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/mpfr/#download which depends on MPFR available at https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/#download which in turn depends on GMP available at https://gmplib.org/#DOWNLOAD

Then the code needs to be linked with -lgmp and -lmpfr.